# problem with fovis

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, kinect, fovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I tried to run fovis fovis_mono_depth_odometer then I used freenect_camera to get data from my kinect

I wrote this launch file for that:

```
<launch>

<remap from="/camera/rgb/image_rect" to="/rgb/image_raw"/>
<remap from="/camera/rgb/camera_info" to="/rgb/camera_info"/>
<remap from="/camera/depth_registered/image_rect" to="/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
<remap from="/camera/depth_registered/camera_info" to="/depth_registered/camera_info"/>
<node
    pkg="fovis_ros"
    type="fovis_mono_depth_odometer"
    name="fovis"
    output="screen"
/>

<node
    pkg="freenect_camera"
    type="freenect_node"
    name="Driver"
    output="screen"
/>

</launch>
```

But I got this err:

[ERROR] [1400343285.543323291]: Depth image must be in 32bit floating point format!

This is  graph of my nodes
[image: image description]

and fovis didn't work.

any suggestion about my problem?

Thanks

Hamid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166176/problem-with-fovis/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2014-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used this launch file and  openni.launch in openni_launch

```
<launch>
<remap from="/camera/rgb/image_rect" to="/camera/rgb/image_color"/>
<remap from="/camera/depth_registered/image_rect" to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>


<remap from="/camera/depth_registered/camera_info" to="/camera/depth/camera_info"/>

<remap from="/camera/depth_registered/image_rect" to="/camera/depth/image"/>


<node
    pkg="fovis_ros"
    type="fovis_mono_depth_odometer"
    name="fovis"
    output="screen"
        
/>


</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mahyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/4281/mahyar/) on 2014-05-20**:
use http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc instead of remap for having image_rect.